# AngularJS 2: concurrent data access to proprety in an injectable class

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

The whole matter come up when we had a shared component @Injectable. Every component in the app.module.ts can inject it into his own constructor.

```
export class SimpleComponent {
   constructor (private sharedComponent : SharedComponent){}
}
```

I write a method in this class SimpleComponent to set a proprety at the shared component:

```
setPropretyAtSharedComponent {
   this.sharedComponent.setProprety("proprety")
}
```

Presuming that the SharedComponent held:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedComponent {
   proprety :any
constructor() {}
}
setProprety (proprety){
   this.proprety = proprety;
}
```

At this point every thing is OK.
So I was wondering if I had two components at the same page which sets the proprety value of the SharedComponent at meanwhile (concurent access) how I can handle that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's taken care of by the DI framework once you define your `Injectable` service in `providers` in your `module`. Once your service is defined in the module, you can inject it in different components as a singleton.

You can refer to these docs:https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html